# GroovyInterceptable (AOP) and closures

Tags: grails, groovy, aop

I've got a grails app with Service classes that inherit from Groovy's GroovyInterceptable:

```
class customerSerrvice implements GroovyInterceptable {

private List<Customer> customers

def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
    log.debug "=======>INVOKING method [$name] with args:$args"
}

void foo() {
    customers.each { doSomething(it) }
}

void doSomething(Customer cust) { log.debug "doSomething invoked with $cust" }

}
```

The above is a greatly simplified representation, but it gives you the idea. If I call foo() or doSomething() **directly** from another class, the invokeMethod gets called like it is supposed to. However, when foo() calls doSomething(), that call is not intercepted in invokeMethod.

If I change from

`customers.each { doSomething(it) }`

to
`for(Customer cust: customers) { doSomething(cust) }`

then the invokeMethod gets called just fine.

So is there something about closures and GroovyInterceptable that don't go together? Is there any way to get the invokeMethod to work with closures short of changing them all out?

Thanks

Comment: Anybody have ideas? Surely, there are some "Groovy internals" types around here. Else we have an awful lot of closures to change out :(

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed as a bug, old link:
<strike>http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4610</strike>, new link:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4610